# Is it legally allowed to pursue an MBA while pursuing a PhD in Sweden?

Tags: phd, masters, sweden

The title says it all. To elaborate, In Sweden Ph.D. is being considered a formal job and students receive a monthly salary and pay taxes. Therefore, the question is specifically about whether applying and pursuing an MBA in parallel with pursuing Ph.D. is legally feasible or a special type of permission is required from the university?

**Update 1:** I'm aware that it's not recommended to pursue these two demanding degrees together. The question is whether in Sweden it's technically possible or not.

**Update 2:** It's a question related to Sweden, only!

Comment: One or the other is pretty intense, done right. How much do you like to sleep?

Comment: Sure, working on writing your thesis is a walk in the park, doesn't take much time at all... Well, aside from being the most stressful time in a PhD for many people.

Comment: The last 1.5 years is not nearly done, that's when it becomes _the most stressful_, as @JonCuster mentions.

Comment: O no! Why is this a duplicate when the other question is German only??

Comment: @user111388 Is there any difference?

Comment: @user2768: Potentially, yes. Both questions relate to a single country and it is not at all clear from the questions that the answers are the same.

Comment: @user111388 Potentially, yes, but, do you have any basis to reopen the question?

Comment: Neither myself nor @JonCuster are arguing, we're merely speaking from experience. Perhaps you have an explanation, but 1.5 years is about forty percent of the time allowed for a PhD in Sweden. Realistically, it's far higher in terms of workload, since earlier years aren't as efficient.

Comment: @user2768: Of course not, I am not a user with much reputation here and as such, I don't have much voice. I am just saying that to me the questions seem to be really unrelated and there is no indication in the questions that they have the same answer.

Comment: @user111388 I only asked to see if the question needed reopening. Since you have no basis, I won't nominate for reopening.

Comment: @user2768: I know the way the site works, this question will not be reopened. My opinion is that closing two questions of different countries as a duplicate is the same of closing any two unrelated questions (where I would also have no basis to reopen other that they are unrelated). I think my problem is that there is no basis to close in the first place.

Comment: @user111388 We have different opinions on how this site works. Questions that get incorrectly closed get reopened, I've argued in favor of many reopenings, but I can't do so without a basis.

Comment: @linker All responses are based on interpretations of the information you've provided. You can edit your question to correct misinterpretations. Regarding differences between contract duration and study periods, I think that's typically across Europe. In countries with shorter contracts, students overrun, whereas students with longer contracts underrun.

Comment: @user2768 I guess the question is crystal clear. Especially with the last 2 updates. I also asked for answers specifically for Sweden! Regarding contracts, In Sweden, one can overrun almost indefinitely, without getting a salary from the university. It's possible to underrun as well (like myself), but almost nobody does that, simply because we're getting salaries and our visas/citizenships are based on that (unless we get a better position elsewhere and/or don't care about visa/citizenship).

Comment: Looking over this, I'm a bit confused as to why location constraints would change anything. I would suggest that the burden would be on you, as the OP, to identify why such a constraint should require a different answer. This would be no different than someone else asking the same question "...for women" or "...for Russian speakers", show us why it matters and we can help address the new facts.

Comment: @eykanal Since the question is asking about the legal aspects of pursuing a second degree, the reason that the answer to this question depends on the country is that different countries may have different rules when it comes to pursuing a second degree. E.g., in China, it might be up to the supervisor to let a PhD student pursue a second degree whereas in the U.S it might be a different case. It may also affect the salary or visa/citizenship situation. I believe it's completely based on the country and associated rules and regulations. Hope this answers your question :-)

Comment: Apart from the probable foolhardiness of attempting this, there is a genuine question of legality, which surely varies from region to region. I am resisting the obvious rant about not doing it even if it's legal. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett You are correct that it is not recommended in general, and I already mentioned it in the question.

Comment: @MichelGokanKhan, yes, I did notice that mention, and I was trying to focus other peoples' attention on the (possibly serious) issue of legality, rather than the wisdom of it. :) (Still resisting advice on that! :)

Comment: Does Sweden usually use the typical European-style "get a Masters then do a 3-year PhD" PhDs or the American-style "start a PhD after you finish a Bachelors, with the first two years being equivalent to a Masters"? In the former case, why would you want to waste your time getting a second Masters? In the latter, wouldn't an MBA be a part of the PhD?

Comment: @nick012000 It’s the European style you mentioned. Again, it is not recommended in general. However, there are cases where someone wants to learn about business administration in the final year of PhD with specific goals (e.g., planning for starting up a business after finishing PhD or learn how to invest). Of course you are right that for someone who is about to get a PhD degree, having a second master degree is not the most important part of this scenario

Answer (score -1):

It's surely unlikely that an institute will forbid the simultaneous pursuit of two degrees. However, an MBA and a PhD are both demanding. Pursuing them simultaneously is seemingly a route to failure, unless they are each tackled on a part-time basis.

Comment: @linker Maybe edit your question to clarify your situation. My answer is country-independent: There's surely no reason for any university to forbid the pursuit of two degrees. Regardless, surely no country does universally, so it only makes sense to consider a single institute, making such a question off topic. Since you have a "no sideline" clause in the contract with your university, you cannot be employed elsewhere. That doesn't mean you can't study an MBA elsewhere (since that's not employment, at least, I know of no business school that'll pay you to study).

Comment: It's still not clear to me (seeing such rules from across the Atlantic) where a "full-time employment" (for a PhD) also precludes "a full-time degree program". So far as I can tell, the literal legality of this is not clear. (Apart from the issue of the wisdom of it...)